# Is it possible to sync ebook app with desktop applications?

Tags: kindle, kobo, feature-comparison, ebook-management, sync

Would it be possible to connect an ebook app directly to its PC application equivalent, so that it can synchronise its library without going across the Internet to the store?

e.g. A PC may have a hard-wired LAN connection to connect to an ebook store and download some ebooks.  If there is no 3G or wifi access in the same building, could the phone app then sync with the PC application to download the new ebooks?

This question is not related to a specific ebook publisher, and I'm most interested to do this whit a Kobo or Kindle ereader, or, if this is possible, with either.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, there are standards like USB... perhaps you must indicate model, etc. Apple and Amazon not respect  standards, but [Kobo yes](http://www.amazon.ca/Kobo-eReader-Glo-USB-Cable/dp/B00AXZVE48): [see item 3 here](http://answers.ccclib.org/a.php?qid=80117)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention if you wanted to do this over the network or over USB.

I've personally used the following approaches:

- The Kobo app automatically syncs directly with the Kobo device when you attach the device to a computer using a USB cable.
- I can copy ebooks files directly to my Kindle and/or Android phone when attached to my computer using normal drag-and-drop.
- I can email ebook files to my Android phone and/or use Dropbox to access them, and when I click on them on the phone, they get copied to my local storage for reading.

None of these require accessing the ebook store from the mobile device.

Comment: True, also, you can just copy ebooks to Kobo from your PC, means that you can do synchronization with any basic program that is able to copy a file from one drive to another.